# How this particular hose works?

Tags: ford, brake-booster, vacuum-hoses

[image: Brake booster hose]

Anyone can explain how the "yellow" hose works? it seems to be 2 hose stack together in the middle. What connection is it and how is it works? Like where the vacuum flow inside those hose?

The reason I asked, I needed vacuum hose to inject "CRC valve intake clearner", could I inject via point "B" of the yellow hose without any issue to brake booster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to inject a cleaner, and don't need to drive it at all for that process, then I would remove the pipe labelled A and find a short length of temporary pipe to fit to the throttle body in place of the pipe labelled A to use to inject the cleaner.

It is also good practice to plug the open end of pipe A while doing this work.

Once cleaning is done then remove the temporary pipe and refit pipe A, making sure to remove the blanking plug / material.

Edited based on the valid comment of Paulster2, thanks.